# comparing ajax's response - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to compare ajax's response with some div's contents which i'm appending from the response ajax.

```
function triggerLoc()
{
    var htmlCont = $('#Pre_Div').text();
    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "url",                
      success : function(data){
           var txt = $(data).text();
           if(htmlCont != txt)
           {
               $('#Pre_Div').prepend(data);
           }
           else
           {
               alert('Content is same');
           }
          setTimeout(triggerLoc, 2000); 
      }
}
```

My ajax success data looks exactly like this after converting it to `text()`

```
                      Name - B7
                      Location - cant-1
                      [12-08-2015 17:45:35 (27 minutes ago) ]





                      Name - A1
                      Location - pro-1
                      [12-08-2015 17:43:50 (29 minutes ago) ]






                      Name - B7
                      Location - cant-2
                      [12-08-2015 17:46:42 (26 minutes ago) ]





                      Name - A1
                      Location - pro-2
                      [12-08-2015 17:44:35 (28 minutes ago) ]
```

Which includes spaces, line breaks. So settimeout for every 2 seconds, the controls goes inside `if(htmlCont != txt)` everytime even though the text is same. My alert wont execute. how to compare ajax response with my appended html contents?

Comment: use trim() eg $(data).text().trim()

Comment: this is working for the first time.. not when called on settimeout.

Comment: data variable is json I think ?

Comment: Why would it be the same? The times will change. Using `text()` on a huge block of html is not going to be a very good comparison mechanism

Comment: Yeah, your response will be in JSON or XML so comparing text directly on that is going to get wonky since your trying to parse the JSON object into text in a weird way. Also, your prepending an object to an HTML element which has some problems itself. I think your solution would be to parse the response object, maybe JSON.stringify(data) and then try to compare that.

Comment: @user3721305 first of All why you need to do like this $(data).text(); because you can easily find the text from the data as the responce will be in object so you can achieve it by keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume data variable is JSON. I highly **not recommend** to do comparison with JSON and DOM way.

You can do the comparison with JavaScript variables. Create a empty variable, then assign a value on first call of ajax function. You can compare this way.

```
var appliedData;

function triggerLoc() {

    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "url",                
      success : function(data) {

           // Check applied data on DOM with new data is same

           if ( appliedData != data ) {

               appliedData = data;
               // Assign new value to global variable.

               $('#Pre_Div').prepend(data); 
               // I recommend change this line. Parse json to html and append it

           } else {

               alert('Content is same');

           }

           setTimeout(triggerLoc, 2000); 

      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. But I removed my timestamp while assiging my data to `appliedData`. because every time the `time` will change.. And it worked..